# Postgresql ALTER TABLE ADD KEY equivalent

Tags: postgresql, alter-table

What is the equivalent of this in postgresql ?

```
--
-- Index for the table `Artist`
--
ALTER TABLE `Artist`
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idArtist`),
    ADD UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`,`firstName`);
    ADD KEY `idFilm` (`idFilm`);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a primary key is the same.

```
alter table artist
  add primary key (idartist);
```

For the unique constraint you have two choices:

```
alter table artist
  add constraint name unique (name, firstname);
```

or a unique index:

```
create unique index name on artist (name, firstname);
```

I think the `key` thing, simply adds a regular index:

```
create index idfilm on artist (idfilm);
```

Comment: A unique constraint is implemented behind the scenes as a unique index. The difference is that the index is "owned" by the table, so it gets dropped automagically if the owning table is dropped.

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax: if you create a unique constraint it is also automatically dropped when you drop the table (including the index that was created implicitly)

Comment: Thank's for you answer! Just a syntaxe error, you need to provide the keyword INDEX before the field name: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "name" on "Artist" ("name","firstName");` [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/indexes-unique.html)